# How do I move this data from a database to increase performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, performance

Need some javascript help.

I have a table in a database that tells me which web elements to show, based on a key numeric property. Based on the key, there are 4 boolean values. Currently, I do a ajax postback to the server but need something faster.

I want to create a function where I pass the key value and I get the 4 values back without a postback. The values are static. Some of my users will be on a slow connection and almost all visit the site frequently, so I could gain by caching.

What's the best way to do this?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Key     Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4
100       0        0        0        1
143       1        0        1        0
785       1        1        1        0
2654      0        1        0        1
2699      1        1        0        1
```

The table has about 500 combinations.

Comment: you could try caching the result on IIS

Comment: please post your table structure and number of rows

Comment: why not load the values to the page initially? no post back, you're golden? in addition, if they values are static and do not change per user, add them to the application cache, and only get them from the db when not available.

Comment: I load the initial value initially. However, almost 100% of the time, I will need to get the updated data because the user will add data that changes what needs to be shown and what needs to be hidden. The values are in application cache so I make only 1 trip to the database. I want to avoid the latency of the postback.

Comment: Can you move the logic of showing/hidding items on the client side ?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I want to move everything to a js file that's cached. Then I run a function that queries the cached items for quick turn around and no latency.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create many static files - every contain JSON for particular key and named as this key.
2. If you have big budget and need REALLY HIGH PERFOMANCE you can use inmemory database like timesten and write custom module for nginx. This will allow to get about 100k reqs/second on average desktop pc with keep-alive.

Comment: As far as I see, the problem stated in the question is network latency, not database load